# Can some one please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RThzA.png)
I am fairly new to code but i have this code below that mostly works, but I need it to say "You have {0} eggs which equals {1} dozen and {2} egg left over." when it has only one egg leftover and eggs when more than one leftover. At the moment it only says "eggs" left over and I have no idea how to change this??

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader;

namespace Q2
{
    public class Q2
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            // Keep the following line intact 
            Console.WriteLine("===========================");

            // Insert your solution here.
            int totaleggs = 0;

            
            Console.Write("Enter the number of chickens: ");
            int Chickens = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            for (int i = 0; i < Chickens; i++)
            {
                
                Console.Write("Eggs: ");
                int egg = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                if (egg > 0)
                {
                    totaleggs += egg;
                    Console.WriteLine("You have {0} eggs which equals {1} dozen and {2} eggs left over.", totaleggs, (int)(totaleggs / 12), totaleggs % 12);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
                else if (totaleggs % 12 ==1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You have {0} eggs which equals {1} dozen and {2} egg left over.", totaleggs, (int)(totaleggs / 12),  totaleggs % 12);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You have {0} eggs which equals {1} dozen and {2} eggs left over.", totaleggs, (int)(totaleggs / 12), totaleggs % 12);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
            
            // Keep the following lines intact
            Console.WriteLine("===========================");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to use the debugger in Visual Studio?

Comment: Would it not make more sense to display your totals once (i.e. after your `for` loop)?

Comment: The title is supposed to summarise the problem. Your title is as much use as no title at all.

Comment: As long as you have `egg > 0`, it will match `if (egg > 0)` and not check `else if (totaleggs % 12 ==1)`

Comment: Although your program being overly complicated (you can remove all `else` clauses) it appears to work fine. Please [edit] and show an example of input along with expected and actual output.

Comment: @Jabberwocky i tried but it says no issues were found

Comment: @josnajose please read my last comment and comply. Your description is very unclear.

Comment: @josnajose in other words: Show the exact text you want to be displayed for following cases: 1 egg, 11 eggs, 12 eggs, 13 eggs, 24 eggs, 25 eggs.

Comment: @josnajose don't show pictures of text, show text as properly formatted text. And the picture you showed doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I have attached the screenshot of the output received, even when i remove the else statements it displays the same output screen. However instead of it saying "one eggs left over" i need it to be singular when only one egg is leftover and say "one egg left over". Hope that makes more sense!

Comment: @josnajose OK, now that's more clear. What about "dozen"? does it also need to be singuralized, like "1 dozen" vs "2 doeznd**s**"?

Comment: @Jabberwocky no dozen is fine as it, it does not matter if its singular or plural

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you want to get something like that (as far as I understand it).

```
Enter the number of chickens: 2
Eggs: 13
You have 13 eggs which equals 1 dozen and 1 egg left over.

Eggs: 15
You have 28 eggs which equals 2 dozen and 4 eggs left over.
```

Then there are several options.

**Option 1 (best way):**

This is a one-liner if, may look hard but when understood. Then will love them.

Link to learn:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator

Option 2 is the same but the "messy" variant

Code:

```
Console.WriteLine("You have {0} eggs which equals {1} dozen and {2} {3} left over.", totaleggs, (int)(totaleggs / 12), totaleggs % 12, totaleggs % 12 == 1 ? "egg" : "eggs");
```

**Option 2:**

Code:

```
string word;

if (totaleggs % 12 == 1)
{
   word = "egg";
}    
else
{
   word = "eggs";
}
                        
Console.WriteLine("You have {0} eggs which equals {1} dozen and {2} {3} left over.", totaleggs, (int)(totaleggs / 12), totaleggs % 12, word);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: @josnajose here is a link in case you want to have a closer look or want to understand (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator)

Answer (score 1):

"*At the moment it only says "eggs" left over and I have no idea how to change this??*"

One way to change this would be to compute all that needs to be written, then write it once:

```cs
int egg = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
// proceed only if the chicken has at least 1 egg
if (egg > 0)
{
    totaleggs += egg;
    int dozens = totaleggs/12;
    int eggsLeft = totaleggs%12;
    // will add an "s" only if more than 1 egg left
    string plural = eggsLeft > 1 ? "s" : "";

    Console.WriteLine("You have {0} eggs which equals {1} dozen and {2} egg{3} left over.", totaleggs, dozens, eggsLeft, plural);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

**Note:** This way, if you need to change the sentence, you will only have to change it once.

---

"*Can some one please tell me what I am doing wrong?*"

You are wrongly using `if/else if` because you will only check the amount of eggs left if there is less than 1 egg for your chicken (*i.e* if the first condition - `egg > 0` - is `false`).

The less changing way to make your code work would be to move the `else if` part *inside* your first `if`, *i.e* change this:

```cs
if (egg > 0)
{
    totaleggs += egg;
    Console.WriteLine("You have {0} eggs which equals {1} dozen and {2} eggs left over.", totaleggs, (int)(totaleggs / 12), totaleggs % 12);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
else if (totaleggs % 12 ==1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("You have {0} eggs which equals {1} dozen and {2} egg left over.", totaleggs, (int)(totaleggs / 12),  totaleggs % 12);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("You have {0} eggs which equals {1} dozen and {2} eggs left over.", totaleggs, (int)(totaleggs / 12), totaleggs % 12);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

for this:

```cs
if (egg > 0)
{
    totaleggs += egg;
    if (totaleggs % 12 ==1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You have {0} eggs which equals {1} dozen and {2} egg left over.", totaleggs, (int)(totaleggs / 12),  totaleggs % 12);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You have {0} eggs which equals {1} dozen and {2} eggs left over.", totaleggs, (int)(totaleggs / 12), totaleggs % 12);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

or, if you still want to print something if there is no egg, just changing `else if` to `if` (and still remove the print from the first `if`):

```cs
if (egg > 0)
{
    totaleggs += egg;
    //Console.WriteLine("You have {0} eggs which equals {1} dozen and {2} eggs left over.", totaleggs, (int)(totaleggs / 12), totaleggs % 12);
    //Console.ReadLine();
}
/* else */ if (totaleggs % 12 ==1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("You have {0} eggs which equals {1} dozen and {2} egg left over.", totaleggs, (int)(totaleggs / 12),  totaleggs % 12);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("You have {0} eggs which equals {1} dozen and {2} eggs left over.", totaleggs, (int)(totaleggs / 12), totaleggs % 12);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: The question is "Can some one please tell me what I am doing wrong?" Your answer doesn't address this. You're answering a question that wasn't asked.

Comment: @Enigmativity I think I answered the "*At the moment it only says "eggs" left over and I have no idea how to change this??*" question

Comment: @Rafalon - Then you need to explain how to change the OP's code to make it work. Not write a new implementation. The OP is quite clear about the two questions asked. It's OK for you to propose a new solution, but answer the question first, or, at the very least, declare you are not answering the question directly but proposing a new solution instead.

Answer (score 1):

In your code your first `if` clause is this:

```
if (egg > 0)
```

That means, so long as `egg` is a non-zero, positive integer, then you execute the body of the iff ***and ignore all `else` statements after it***.

You need to check for the `totaleggs % 12 == 1` condition before the `egg > 0` condition.

Your `for` loop needs to look like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Chickens; i++)
{
    Console.Write("Eggs: ");
    int egg = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    totaleggs += egg;

    if (totaleggs % 12 == 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You have {0} eggs which equals {1} dozen and {2} egg left over.", totaleggs, totaleggs / 12, totaleggs % 12);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You have {0} eggs which equals {1} dozen and {2} eggs left over.", totaleggs, totaleggs / 12, totaleggs % 12);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Side-note: you don't need to write `(int)(totaleggs / 12)` as `totaleggs / 12` does exactly the same thing.

---

If I were writing this, I'd do something more like this:

```
int totaleggs = 0;

int ReadNumber()
{
    while (true)
    {
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        if (int.TryParse(input, out int result) && result > 0)
        {
            return result;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Not a valid number. Please try again.");
    }
}

Console.Write("Enter the number of chickens: ");
int chickens = ReadNumber();

for (int i = 0; i < chickens; i++)
{
    Console.Write("Eggs: ");
    int egg = ReadNumber();
    
    totaleggs += egg;

    int dozens = totaleggs / 12;
    int singles = totaleggs % 12;
    
    string singles_text =
        singles == 1
        ? "1 egg"
        : $"{singles} eggs";

    Console.WriteLine($"You have {totaleggs} eggs which equals {dozens} dozen and {singles_text} left over.");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You probably want the content of your for loop be something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Chickens; i++)
{
    Console.Write("Eggs: ");
    int egg = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    totaleggs += egg;

    int eggs = totaleggs;
    int dozen = totaleggs / 12;
    int leftover = totaleggs % 12;

    string stotaleggs;
    if (eggs == 1)
        stotaleggs = "egg";
    else
        stotaleggs = "eggs";

    string sleftover;
    if (leftover == 1)
        sleftover = "egg";
    else
        sleftover = "eggs";

    Console.WriteLine("You have {0} {3} which equals {1} dozen and {2} {4} left over.", eggs, dozen, leftover, stotaleggs, sleftover);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

It's pretty self explaining.

This can probably be written in a more elegant way, but you should get the idea.